# unitofwork, repositories and disposing of connections

Tags: c#, repository, sqlconnection

I have a unitofWork class and a repository that uses it
something along the lines of this:

## unit of work

```
private SqlConnection _conn;
private TransactionScope _ts;

public UnitOfWork(SqlConnection conn, TransactionScope ts)
{
    _ts = ts;
    _conn = conn;
    _conn.EnlistTransaction(Transaction.Current);
}

public SqlConnection Connection
{
    get { return _conn; }
}

public void Save()
{
    _ts.Complete();
}

#region IDisposable

public void Dispose()
{
    if (_conn != null)
    {
        _conn.Dispose();
        _conn = null;
    }

    if (_ts != null)
    {
        _ts.Dispose();
        _conn = null;
    }
}
```

## repository

```
SqlConnection _conn;

public Repository(IUnitOfWork uow)
{
    _conn = uow.Connection;
}
// some methods
public void Dispose()
{
    if (_conn != null)
    {
        _conn.Dispose();
        _conn = null;
    }
}
```

I am using it like this

```
using (var uow = new UnitOfWork())
{
    using (var repo = new Repository(uow))
    {
        if (repo.UpdateStuff())
        {
            uow.Save();
        }
    }
}
```

the dispose method is first called in the repo, which disposes and nulls the connection. but then when it we get to the uow dispose, the connection is no longer null and is disposed 'again'
I am sure I am being dull, but can anyone explain please

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The right part of the statement

```
_conn = uow.Connection;
```

actually returns a copy of the object reference, not the reference itself.

So what you're setting to null in the Repository Dispose method is the local reference to the connection, which is different from the connection reference in the UnitOfWork instance.

If you really want to keep this behavior ( having the UnitOfWork Connection property set to null by the Repository Code), you must set the uow.Connection to null, not the local reference _conn.

Comment: so i should simply not make the repo idisposable and leave that to the dispose of the UOW. i did it like that so i could write this:
using (var repo = new Repository(new UnitOfWork())){}

Comment: The question is : "Does the repository have to dispose and free the UoW connection ?". To me, it is more the UoW job.